# android animation to expand a circular image in all direction

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

on button click i am trying to show a animation on a circular image. On Click action I need the image to be zoomed in all 360degree.

At first the image will be as follows

[image] after onClick action i want the image to be as follows

[image] , bigger than the actual size, until again the button is clicked it must be the same

I am using the following code:

```
TranslateAnimation moveAnim = new TranslateAnimation(-25, -25, -25, -25);
        moveAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        moveAnim.setDuration(600);
        moveAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
        moveAnim.setFillAfter(true);
        moveAnim.setRepeatMode(AnimationSet.REVERSE);
        moveAnim.setRepeatCount(AnimationSet.INFINITE);
        startAnimation(moveAnim);
```

by this the image gets moved slightly from its position and not getting expanded.

how to expand the image in `onclick` and again in another click the image to be moved to its original position

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will do the job (/res/anim/myanim.xml):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromXScale="0.1"
      android:toXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="0.1"
      android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:duration="600"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%" >
   </scale>
</set>
```

and in your fragment ( or activity or whatever you are using):

```
    public class TestZoomFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);

        Button btnZoom = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.test_btn_zoom);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.test_img);

        btnZoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.zoom);
                image.startAnimation(animation);                
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

By the way, if you want the image to be invisible before button is clicked, just set the default visibility to be "gone" and set it back to be "visible" in `OnClick()`.

Ref:
    [Android Animations Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm)

The test_layout.xml is just simple. But in case someone need it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_btn_zoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text="zoom!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very late but might help someone:

new translate animation parameters are (fromXDelta,toXDelta,fromYDelta,toYDelta) as you are giving all values as -25 it doesnt do anything.

try with

```
    TranslateAnimation moveAnim = new TranslateAnimation(-25, 25, -25, 25);
    moveAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    moveAnim.setDuration(600);
    moveAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    moveAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    moveAnim.setRepeatMode(AnimationSet.REVERSE);
    moveAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
    yourImageView.startAnimation(moveAnim);
```